# Cannot install libpq-devel on Oracle Linux 8

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, libpq, oraclelinux

As background, I'm trying to install psycopg2 on an Oracle Linux 8 server. Attempting to install psycopg2 in a virtual environment (Python 3.9) via `python3 -m pip install --user psycopg2` leads to an error, the significant bit of which seems to be this:

```
...
      In file included from psycopg/adapter_asis.c:28:
      ./psycopg/psycopg.h:36:10: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
       #include <libpq-fe.h>
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
...
```

Per the [install docs for psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html), this suggests that libpq-dev is needed. Checking for available packages via `sudo dnf search libpq-dev`, I see the following:

```
libpq-devel.i686 : Development files for building PostgreSQL client tools
libpq-devel.x86_64 : Development files for building PostgreSQL client tools
```

The latter of these appears to be the package I need. However, running `sudo dnf install libpq-devel.x86_64` gives me the following error:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 3:06:02 ago on Wed 10 Aug 2022 04:25:26 AM MST.
Error:
 Problem: problem with installed package libpq5-14.0-42PGDG.rhel8.x86_64
  - installed package libpq5-14.0-42PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 obsoletes libpq provided by libpq-13.5-1.el8.x86_64
  - package libpq5-14.3-42PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 obsoletes libpq provided by libpq-13.5-1.el8.x86_64
  - package libpq5-14.4-42PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 obsoletes libpq provided by libpq-13.5-1.el8.x86_64
  - package libpq-devel-13.5-1.el8.x86_64 requires libpq(x86-64) = 13.5-1.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best candidate for the job
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Based on [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/623481/yum-update-returns-conflicts-with-postgresql), I tried disabling all PostgreSQL repos, e.g., `sudo dnf config-manager --set-disabled pgdg10`, leaving only the default Oracle Linux repos:

```
$ dnf repolist
repo id                                                                                    repo name
ol8_UEKR6                                                                                  Latest Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel Release 6 for Oracle Linux 8 (x86_64)
ol8_appstream                                                                              Oracle Linux 8 Application Stream (x86_64)
ol8_baseos_latest                                                                          Oracle Linux 8 BaseOS Latest (x86_64)
ol8_developer_EPEL                                                                         Oracle Linux 8 EPEL Packages for Development (x86_64)
```

After doing this, then trying the install again via `sudo dnf install libpq-devel.x86_64`, I'm getting a different error (progress?):

```
Error:
 Problem: installed package postgresql10-devel-10.21-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 obsoletes libpq-devel provided by libpq-devel-13.5-1.el8.x86_64
  - cannot install the best candidate for the job
  - problem with installed package postgresql10-devel-10.21-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Adding the `--skip-broken` flag just gives the `Dependencies resolved. Nothing to do.` message; adding the `nobest` flag throws the following:

```
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - installed package postgresql10-devel-10.21-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 obsoletes libpq-devel provided by libpq-devel-10.5-1.el8.x86_64
  - installed package postgresql10-devel-10.21-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 obsoletes libpq-devel provided by libpq-devel-12.1-3.el8.x86_64
  - installed package postgresql10-devel-10.21-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 obsoletes libpq-devel provided by libpq-devel-12.4-1.el8_2.x86_64
  - installed package postgresql10-devel-10.21-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 obsoletes libpq-devel provided by libpq-devel-12.5-1.el8_3.x86_64
  - installed package postgresql10-devel-10.21-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 obsoletes libpq-devel provided by libpq-devel-13.2-1.el8.x86_64
  - installed package postgresql10-devel-10.21-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 obsoletes libpq-devel provided by libpq-devel-13.3-1.el8_4.x86_64
  - installed package postgresql10-devel-10.21-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 obsoletes libpq-devel provided by libpq-devel-13.5-1.el8.x86_64
  - problem with installed package postgresql10-devel-10.21-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

Using both flags together gives:

```
Dependencies resolved.

 Problem: installed package postgresql10-devel-10.21-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 obsoletes libpq-devel provided by libpq-devel-13.5-1.el8.x86_64
  - cannot install the best candidate for the job
  - problem with installed package postgresql10-devel-10.21-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

I'm at a loss as far as how to proceed.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to do `python3 -m pip install --user psycopg2-binary`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I'm not sure that counts as a "solution", though, since the docs specifically warn against using psycopg2-binary in production environments. https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#psycopg-vs-psycopg-binary

Comment: I said simplest not best. From the looks of it you are currently have Postgres 13 installed.  I am not familiar with Oracle Linux, but you might try something along line of `sudo dnf install postgresql13-devel`. You might have to search for the exact package name.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thank you! I have PostgreSQL 12 installed, and your suggestion prompted me to try ```sudo dnf install postgresql12-devel```. It hadn't dawned on me that this was a proper way to meet the install requirements for psycopg2. After doing that, I hit the issue related to the install not finding pg_config, so I added to PATH via ```export PATH=/usr/pgsql-12/bin/:$PATH```. After that, I was able to install psycopg2 via pip with no issues. Do you want to write up your comment as an answer, so I can accept?

Comment: Nah,  it's all good.